# Laravel ajax file upload method not allowed

Tags: ajax, laravel, file-upload

Using Laravel 5.4
I'm trying to submit a form with a file to upload with ajax.

My jquery code:

```
$("#uploadRoastsForm").submit(function() {
var url = $(this).attr('action');
var fd = new FormData();    
var files = $('#roastFile')[0].files;    

if(files.length > 0)
    fd.append('file', files[0]);

fd.append('file', files[0]);
fd.append('roast_date', $('#roastDate').val());
    
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: fd,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {...
```

My form:

```
<form action="/warehouse/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form" id="uploadRoastsForm">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                
                <div class="form-group" style="width:150px">
                    <label>Roasting Date</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input name="roast_date" type="text" value="{{ old('roast_date') }}" class="form-control datepick" id="roastDate">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Upload Roast Files</label>
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="roastFile">
                </div>
```

I am getting this in firebug:
XHRPOSThttp://highland.local/warehouse/upload
[HTTP/1.1 419 unknown status 250ms]

```
message ""
exception   
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler.php"
line    204
trace   [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
0   Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler.php", line: 176, function: "prepareException", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler.php"
line    176
function    "prepareException"
class   "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler"
type    "->"
1   Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\app\\Exceptions\\Handler.php", line: 77, function: "render", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\app\\Exceptions\\Handler.php"
line    77
function    "render"
class   "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler"
type    "->"
2   Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php", line: 83, function: "render", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php"
line    83
function    "render"
class   "App\\Exceptions\\Handler"
type    "->"
3   Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php", line: 55, function: "handleException", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php"
line    55
function    "handleException"
class   "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline"
type    "->"
4   Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession.php", line: 49, function: "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession.php"
line    49
function    "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}"
class   "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline"
type    "->"
5   Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php", line: 163, function: "handle", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php"
line    163
function    "handle"
class   "Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession"
type    "->"
6   Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php", line: 53, function: "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php"
line    53
function    "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}"
class   "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline"
type    "->"
7   Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php", line: 63, function: "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php"
line    63
function    "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}"
class   "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline"
type    "->"
8   Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php", line: 163, function: "handle", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php"
line    163
function    "handle"
class   "Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession"
type    "->"
9   Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php", line: 53, function: "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php"
line    53
function    "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}"
class   "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline"
type    "->"
10  Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php", line: 37, function: "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php"
line    37
function    "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}"
class   "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline"
type    "->"
11  Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php", line: 163, function: "handle", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php"
line    163
function    "handle"
class   "Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse"
type    "->"
12  Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php", line: 53, function: "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php"
line    53
function    "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}"
class   "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline"
type    "->"
13  Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies.php", line: 66, function: "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies.php"
line    66
function    "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}"
class   "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline"
type    "->"
14  Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php", line: 163, function: "handle", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php"
line    163
function    "handle"
class   "Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies"
type    "->"
15  Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php", line: 53, function: "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php"
line    53
function    "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}"
class   "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline"
type    "->"
16  Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php", line: 104, function: "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php"
line    104
function    "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}"
class   "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline"
type    "->"
17  Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php", line: 684, function: "then", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php"
line    684
function    "then"
class   "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline"
type    "->"
18  Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php", line: 659, function: "runRouteWithinStack", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php"
line    659
function    "runRouteWithinStack"
class   "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router"
type    "->"
19  Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php", line: 625, function: "runRoute", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php"
line    625
function    "runRoute"
class   "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router"
type    "->"
20  Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php", line: 614, function: "dispatchToRoute", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php"
line    614
function    "dispatchToRoute"
class   "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router"
type    "->"
21  Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php", line: 176, function: "dispatch", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php"
line    176
function    "dispatch"
class   "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router"
type    "->"
22  Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php", line: 30, function: "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php"
line    30
function    "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}"
class   "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel"
type    "->"
23  Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\app\\Http\\Middleware\\ForceSsl.php", line: 29, function: "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\app\\Http\\Middleware\\ForceSsl.php"
line    29
function    "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}"
class   "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline"
type    "->"
24  Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php", line: 163, function: "handle", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php"
line    163
function    "handle"
class   "App\\Http\\Middleware\\ForceSsl"
type    "->"
25  Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php", line: 53, function: "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php"
line    53
function    "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}"
class   "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline"
type    "->"
26  Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php", line: 31, function: "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php"
line    31
function    "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}"
class   "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline"
type    "->"
27  Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php", line: 163, function: "handle", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php"
line    163
function    "handle"
class   "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest"
type    "->"
28  Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php", line: 53, function: "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php"
line    53
function    "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}"
class   "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline"
type    "->"
29  Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php", line: 31, function: "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php"
line    31
function    "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}"
class   "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline"
type    "->"
30  Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php", line: 163, function: "handle", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php"
line    163
function    "handle"
class   "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest"
type    "->"
31  Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php", line: 53, function: "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php"
line    53
function    "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}"
class   "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline"
type    "->"
32  Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php", line: 27, function: "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php"
line    27
function    "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}"
class   "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline"
type    "->"
33  Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php", line: 163, function: "handle", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php"
line    163
function    "handle"
class   "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize"
type    "->"
34  Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php", line: 53, function: "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php"
line    53
function    "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}"
class   "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline"
type    "->"
35  Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php", line: 104, function: "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php"
line    104
function    "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}"
class   "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline"
type    "->"
36  Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php", line: 151, function: "then", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php"
line    151
function    "then"
class   "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline"
type    "->"
37  Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php", line: 116, function: "sendRequestThroughRouter", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php"
line    116
function    "sendRequestThroughRouter"
class   "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel"
type    "->"
38  Object { file: "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\public\\index.php", line: 53, function: "handle", … }
file    "C:\\wamp64\\www\\highland.local\\public\\index.php"
line    53
function    "handle"
class   "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel"
type    "->"
```

I also tried to have an input as a submit button on the form and when I click it I call the exact same ajax, but then I got the error: MethodNotAllowed.

Something breaks when I use: contentType: false, processData: false. But if I don't use them I can't send the file to the controller.
Can anyone help please?

How do you upload file with ajax in Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

At first you didn't posted what is the method in your `route/web.php` for your ajax request.

If it is `MethodNotAllowed` related problem then probably your ajax request and route method is not same.

If you are trying to update something then use PUT method in your route like below

```php
Route::put('/warehouse/upload', "WarehouseController@upload');
```

And if you are trying to insert data into database table then use `POST` method:

```php
Route::post('/warehouse/upload', "WarehouseController@upload');
```

As you are using POST method from your jQuery AJAX function, then just use post method in your route.

I think it should solve your query.

Comment: Hi @Surajit, thank you but I don't think that's it. I use Post and I create and update the database. When I don't use Ajax, everything is fine.

Comment: Can you please post the controller method with existing code.